# How to resolve chroot. Bin /bash not finding the file or directory

Tags: linux, boot-loader, chroot, parrotsec

[image: this is what i've been trying to do]
After Windows update, grub bootloader is not showing up.

So I have followed the exact steps from

```
https://docs.parrotlinux.org/trbl/trbl-grub/#3-now-you-have-to-mount-the-partitions
```

so the steps mentioned in parrrotlinux.org:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount --bind /proc/ mnt/proc   // used mkdir to create proc, sys, dev on /mnt
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
if u use EFI partition:
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi // if mount point dosent exist, then mkdir /mnt/boot | mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
chroot /mnt  
grub-install /dev/sda
exit
```

And I'm facing problem in changing the root directory (the picture describes it all).

I'm new to this, so please give me detailed steps to resolve the issue.

P.S. I have referred to similar questions in this platform but none of them resolved my issue.

```
    mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
    ls /mnt 
# boot   dev   EFI   proc   run   sys  'System Volume Information'
```

Comment: After the `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`, can you edit into the question the output of `ls /mnt`? If it doesn't include `/bin` can you replace the `/dev/sda1` with `/dev/sda2` and repeat the other commands.

Comment: /mnt doesnt have /bin directory,  and /dev/sda2  is the root partition,

Comment: mount /dev/sda2 /mnt    chroot /mnt   grub-install /dev/sda gives error:#grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.

Comment: So /dev/sda2 is the thing that you want mounted on /mnt, and /dev/sda1 is the thing you want mounted on /mnt/boot/efi. With the bind mounts of /proc, /dev, and /sys (maybe also /dev/pts) you should be able to do the `chroot /mnt /bin/bash` successfully. If you can edit into the question the error you are getting it will make things more readable then having them in comments. Currently parrotlinux.org is down for me and archive.org doesn't have your referenced page available.

Comment: Sure ill do that

Comment: There's no `unmount` command. Only `umount`.

Comment: @icarus Thanks alot for guiding through the entire process. It works!! yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the steps to be followed**

`sudo fdisk -l` to view all the partitions and replace your partition name accordingly in the below steps.

we need to mount efi partition into `/mnt/boot/efi`
and `/ (root)` partition into the `/mnt`

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc //if mnt/proc doesnt exist, make that dir using mkdir
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
if u use EFI partition:
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi // if mount point dosent exist, then mkdir /mnt/boot | mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
chroot /mnt 
grub-install /dev/sda
exit
```

reboot
thats it!
grub bootloader will appear again! .